# validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I have a project and in this project I have several interfaces, and among these interfaces I have a login interface, the login interface is working, but I have this error in the console:

```
validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

What caused it and how can I solve it?

And this is the component from which it became clear to me that the ERROR appeared

```
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { darken } from "@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import JWTLoginTab from "./tabs/JWTLoginTab";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${
      theme.palette.primary.dark
    } 0%, ${darken(theme.palette.primary.dark, 0.5)} 100%)`,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  },
  leftSection: {},
  rightSection: {
    background: `linear-gradient(to right, ${
      theme.palette.primary.dark
    } 0%, ${darken(theme.palette.primary.dark, 0.5)} 100%)`,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
  },
}));

function Login() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

  function handleTabChange(event, value) {
    setSelectedTab(value);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(
        classes.root,
        "flex flex-col flex-auto items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 p-16 md:p-24"
      )}
    >
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.6 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
        className="flex w-full max-w-400 md:max-w-3xl rounded-20 shadow-2xl overflow-hidden"
      >
        <Card
          className={clsx(
            classes.leftSection,
            "flex flex-col w-full max-w-sm items-center justify-center shadow-0"
          )}
          square
        >
          <CardContent className="flex flex-col  w-full py-96 max-w-320">
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, transition: { delay: 0.2 } }}
            >
              <div className="flex items-center mb-6">
                <div
                  // justifyContent="flex-start"
                  // alignItems="flex-start"
                  className="flex mb-32"
                >
                  <div>
                    <Typography
                      className="text-20 font-semibold logo-text"
                      color="inherit"
                    >
                      Login
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      className="text-14 tracking-widest -mt-13 font-700 mb-10"
                      color="textSecondary"
                    >
                      fill in your login information
                    </Typography>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </motion.div>

            <JWTLoginTab />
          </CardContent>

          <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pb-32">
            <div>
              <span className="font-normal mr-8">Don't have an account?</span>
              <Link className="font-normal" to="/register">
                Register
              </Link>
            </div>
            <Link className="font-normal mt-8" to="/">
              Back to Dashboard
            </Link>
          </div>
        </Card>

        <div
          className={clsx(
            classes.rightSection,
            "hidden md:flex flex-1 items-center justify-center p-64"
          )}
        >
          <div className="max-w-320">
            <motion.div
              initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 70 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { delay: 0.2 } }}
            >
              <img
                src="assets/images/logos/brick.png"
                color="#F6F7F9"
                width="110rem"
                height="100rem"
              />
            </motion.div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

jwtLoginTab.js:

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { submitLogin } from "app/auth/store/loginSlice";
import * as yup from "yup";
import _ from "@lodash";

/**
 * Form Validation Schema
 */
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("You must enter a valid email")
    .required("You must enter an email"),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .required("Please enter your password.")
    .min(4, "Password is too short - should be 4 chars minimum."),
});

const defaultValues = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

function JWTLoginTab(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const login = useSelector(({ auth }) => auth.login);
  const {
    control,
    setValue,
    formState,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    trigger,
    setError,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const { isValid, dirtyFields, errors } = formState;

  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("email", "ria@ria.com", {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldValidate: true,
    });
    setValue("password", "ria@123", {
      shouldDirty: true,
      shouldValidate: true,
    });
  }, [reset, setValue, trigger]);

  useEffect(() => {
    login?.errors?.forEach((error) => {
      setError(error.type, {
        type: "manual",
        message: error.message,
      });
    });
  }, [login.errors, setError]);

  function onSubmit(model) {
    dispatch(submitLogin(model));
    console.log("2-JWTLoginTab: ", model);
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <form
        className="flex flex-col justify-center w-full"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
        <Controller
          name="email"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <TextField
              {...field}
              className="mb-16"
              type="text"
              error={!!errors.email}
              helperText={errors?.email?.message}
              label="Email"
              InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <Icon className="text-20" color="action">
                      user
                    </Icon>
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
        />

        <Controller
          name="password"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <TextField
              {...field}
              className="mb-16"
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              error={!!errors.password}
              helperText={errors?.password?.message}
              variant="outlined"
              InputProps={{
                className: "pr-2",
                type: showPassword ? "text" : "password",
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}>
                      <Icon className="text-20" color="action">
                        {showPassword ? "visibility" : "visibility_off"}
                      </Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              required
            />
          )}
        />

        <Button
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className="w-full mx-auto mt-16"
          aria-label="LOG IN"
          disabled={_.isEmpty(dirtyFields) || !isValid}
          value="legacy"
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default JWTLoginTab;
```

Comment: Can we also see the contents of `JWTLoginTab`? I don't see anything related to the error in the code you posted, all seems good. Also, doesn't the error print out a trace?

Comment: i edit my post @Gaëtan Boyals

Comment: Since it's a bit difficult to reproduce your code into a minimal example, and I don't see anything wrong with your code just by reading it, I can only explain why this error appears: a `<p>` HTML tag cannot contain `<div>` HTML tags, meaning you can't put a `<div>` inside a `<p>`. Usually, this error pops when you try to put a child in `<Typography>`, since this tag is a `<p>` in disguise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell Typography to be rendered as `span` like so:

```
<Typography component="span">Your Text</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

React render each component you are calling to your screen as a `<div>` element. If peradventure, you called a component inside the `<p>` tag element, this error will occur. This simply means you are rendering a `<div>` inside `<p>` tag. This happens to external modules too,@materialui, @react-bootstrap, and many other modules.

In a visual sense,

```
<p><div></div></p>
```

Comment: can u edit my code?

Comment: I think @Wink check has answered the question for you. Render the `<Typograhpy>` component as `span` should solve the problem. Sorry for the late response